# PyCountry currency formatting woes for 'DE' alpha2 country code

Tags: python, currency-formatting

I have a Python function which accepts an alpha2 country code and a price string, where the aim is to get the country's currency and use the currency.letter property of that currency to format the supplied price string using string interpolation.

The above works fine so far - yet it falls over when called with Germany as the country as follows:

```
>>> import pycountry
>>> country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha2='DE')
>>> currency = pycountry.currencies.get(numeric=country.numeric)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pycountry/db.py", line 83, in get
    return self.indices[field][value]
KeyError: '276'
>>>
```

The `pycountry.countries` collection does not contain a currency with a numeric of 276 (Germany's numeric) - yet it does contain the Euro. Any ideas as to what the way around this may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the country numeric code is NOT the same as the currency numeric. According to the ISO, "[Where possible the 3 digit numeric code is the same as the numeric country code](http://www.iso.org/iso/currency_codes)" - but this is obviously NOT possible for the Euro, which is shared by multiple countries.

The numeric for the Euro is 978, not 276; apparently pycountry doesn't provide a mapping between country numerics and currency numerics.  Here's a link to the raw tables (in XML or XLS format) so you can roll your own, if you so desire...
http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

Answer (score 1):

Not my favorite solution, but it works. I needed a project-wide solution for this problem:

```
# pycountry_patch.py
from pycountry import db, countries, DATABASE_DIR, Currencies as pycountryCurrencies
from django.conf import settings
import os.path

class Currencies(pycountryCurrencies):
    @db.lazy_load
    def get(self, **kw):
        assert len(kw) == 1, 'Only one criteria may be given.'
        field, value = kw.popitem()

        if field == 'numeric' and value in [countries.get(alpha2=x).numeric for x in settings.EUROPEAN_COUNTRIES]:
            value = '978'

        return self.indices[field][value]

currencies = Currencies(os.path.join(DATABASE_DIR, 'iso4217.xml'))
```

and in settings.py (incomplete list):

```
EUROPEAN_COUNTRIES = [
    'DE',  # Germany
    'FR',
    'ES',
    'PT',
    'IT',
    'NL',
]
```

Calling the patched `get`:

```
>>> from modules.core import pycountry_patch
>>> pycountry_patch.currencies.get(numeric='276').name
u'Euro'
```

Comment: PS: The list of countries using the euro here is not complete. Afaik there are 25 countries using the euro.

Comment: EUR_AREA_MEMBERS=['Austria','Belgium','Cyprus','Estonia','Finland','France','Germany','Greece','Ireland','Italy','Latvia','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Malta','Netherlands','Portugal','Slovakia','Slovenia','Spain']
EUR_NON_AREA_MEMBERS=['Bulgaria','Croatia','Czechia','Hungary','Poland','Romania','Sweden']
EUROPEAN_COUNTRIES=EUR_AREA_MEMBERS+EUR_NON_AREA_MEMBERS
EUROPEAN_COUNTRIES_ALPHA_2=['AT', 'BE', 'CY', 'EE', 'FI', 'FR', 'DE', 'GR', 'IE', 'IT', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'PT', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'BG', 'HR', 'CZ', 'HU', 'PL', 'RO', 'SE']

Answer (score 1):

If you want a comprehensive solution getting currency symbols for a given country or territory, you can use `babel.numbers.get_territory_currencies`.

http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html#babel.numbers.get_territory_currencies