# How to get currency symbol from ISO country code in Django application?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I just want to get the Currency symbol for different countries in my Python Django application from the country code I have. For example I have a country code 'US', the output I need is '$' or 'US$'.

Now I achieve this with the help of two libraries, namely pycountry and forex-python. Can I achieve this in a more simple way?

```
import pycountry
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyCodes
code = "US"
country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=code)
currency = pycountry.currencies.get(numeric=country.numeric)
country_codes = CurrencyCodes()
country_codes.get_symbol(currency.alpha_3)
```

Output: **'US$'**

Comment: What do you mean by more simple? Different packages? More efficient code?

Comment: Like using a single package and getting the currency symbol directly from country code

Comment: You'd probably have to write that yourself.The reason is that ISO codes have nothing to do with the `$` symbol.

Comment: This wasn't asked, but your country to currency mapping isn't robust. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461352/pycountry-currency-formatting-woes-for-de-alpha2-country-code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/):

```
from babel.numbers import get_currency_symbol, get_territory_currencies

def currency_symbol(country_code):
    try:
        currency_code = get_territory_currencies(country_code)[0]
        symbol = get_currency_symbol(currency_code, locale='en_US')
    except IndexError:
        symbol = ''
    return symbol
```

Now print to get the output you need:

```
>>> print(currency_symbol('US'))
$
```

Notes:

1. The function will return an empty string when it cannot find the
   country code you entered.
2. The function will return the ISO code for the currency when the symbol does not exist *for the given locale*.

Modify the function according to your needs.